# How can I call a redux action within a setState callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, callback, action

I am trying to call an action imported from another file from within a `setState` callback, but I am getting a type error stating it is not a function.

I have tried moving the function call outside the callback but got the same error, so I am unsure what the issue is. (Though I assume something isn't binding correctly?)

This is the code where the action is called

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { MDBContainer } from "mdbreact";
import FormBuilder from "./FormBuilder";
import { addForm } from "../actions/formActions";

export class FormBuilderContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    formData: []
  };

  onSubmit = (nameArg, formArg) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        name: nameArg.value,
        formData: formArg
      },
      () => {
        const newForm = {
          name: this.state.name,
          formData: this.state.formData
        };

        // Add form via addForm action
        this.props.addForm(newForm);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MDBContainer>
        <FormBuilder formData={this.state.formData} onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
      </MDBContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { addForm }
)(FormBuilderContainer);
```

And the addForm action method

```
export const addForm = form => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/forms", form, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_FORM,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
  console.log("Saved Form");
};
```

The error thrown is:

> TypeError: _this.props.addForm is not a function

```
  30 |                console.log(newForm);
  31 | 
  32 |                // Add form via addForm action
> 33 |                this.props.addForm(newForm);
  34 |            }
  35 |        );
  36 |    };
```

Comment: It looks setup correctly, possibly a stale version of the code? I presume by the error containing `_this` you are using a transpiler, could you try manually rebuilding or cleaning / rebuilding?

Comment: I also believe that you have a problem with your transpiling tool, try `console.log(this.props.addForm)` to see exactly what you have defined on that variable.

Comment: No, I believe it's how he uses/imported the FormBuilderContainer Component. I have an explanation below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is how you import the **FormBuilderContainer** component, as you can see you exported it as:

```
export class FormBuilderContainer extends Component
```

and at the bottom you have:

```
export default connect(
    null,
    { addForm }
)(FormBuilderContainer);
```

Now if you import it using below, then that gives you error:

```
import { FormBuilderContainer } from 'path-to-component-file'
```

You should import it like so:

```
import FormBuilderContainer  from 'path-to-component-file'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This fixed the issue, thank you! Just had to update the file I was importing it to so that it was corrected.

Comment: Glad to help...!